# Can I retrieve both the value and text from the same DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, text, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list of which I need both the text and value.

The value is normally submitted to the database, but I also need the text which the value represents.

Is that possible? And, if so, how?

Comment: The items in a dropdownlist have text and value properties that you can assign values to, but could you be a bit more clear about what you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Yeh you can get both text and value using DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text or
DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedItem` property of a `DropDownList` control is of [type `ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) which contains both a `Text` property and a `Value` property.

When you say "the value is normally submitted to the database" what exactly do you mean?  Are you interacting directly with the `DropDownList` in code?  If so then you should be able to access the `Text` and `Value` properties.  If not, how is it being used?